# using jackson2 modulenotfound

Tags: maven, jboss, jackson, resteasy

I am trying to use jackson2 with RestEasy, Added all the required dependencies and marked the dependencies as "provided" to avoid conflict with JBOSS inbuilt Libs.

POM XML:

```
     <!-- resteasy start -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
              <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
              <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- resteasy end -->

            <!-- jackson imports starts -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- jackson import ends -->


    Deployment structure :

    <jboss-deployment-structure>
      <deployment>
        <exclusions>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
        </dependencies>
      </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But when i try to start the server, JBOSS module not able to find the required lib and failed with the exception.If the deploy structure xml is not there json conversion is working fine but many of the jackson2 properties are ignored.

exception :

org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider:main
          at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]

I have tried with out Scope as 'provided' as well still it fail to start the container.

JBOSS version :  JBoss EAP 6.2.4.GA (AS 7.3.4.Final-redhat-1)

Any insights is really helpful

Thanks

Comment: module not found issue as the JBOSS EAP do not have Jackson2 libs under modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\resteasy. But stil wanted to use RestEasy+Jackson 2 to make use of @JSONView at the Controller level.
`@POST
@JsonView(TEST.class)`
There is no compile/run time error but JSONView is getting ignored, below code just works fine. 
`ObjectMapper _mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        _mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = _mapper.writerWithView(TEST.class);
        String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(response);`

Comment: Did my answer help you @kiran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the required jar in your own module folder in modules\system\layers\base\org\\main and reference it via jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml

Basically just copy the required jar form your .m2 folder and give it to the jboss server to resolve dependencies at runtime. Alternatively, you can also try adding runtime scope to the required jar in your project's POM.

Comment: `<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
      <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>` 

Added Jackson libs to POM so that references to libs are with in project rather than container